How to call androidx CredentialManager's clearCredentialState in Java?
Referring to this method
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/credentials/CredentialManager#clearCredentialState(androidx.credentials.ClearCredentialStateRequest)
I was wondering how I can call it from Java?
I am using the following Java code.
Context context = getContext();

// Initialize the CredentialManager instance
CredentialManager credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context);

// Create a request to clear the credential state
ClearCredentialStateRequest request = new ClearCredentialStateRequest();

credentialManager.clearCredentialState(request);

But, I am getting the following compiler error
required: ClearCredentialStateRequest,Continuation<? super Unit>
found:    ClearCredentialStateRequest
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length


The method signature for clearCredentialState shows that is a suspend method that requires the use of Kotlin Coroutines.
As explained in the documentation for clearCredentialStateAsync:

This API uses callbacks instead of Kotlin coroutines.

So you can use that method for clearing the credential state in Java:
credentialManager.clearCredentialStateAsync(
  request,
  null, // pass in a CancelationSignal to allow cancelling the request
  Runnable::run, // Execute the callback immediately
  new CredentialManagerCallback<Void, ClearCredentialException>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Void result) {
      // Handle success
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull ClearCredentialException e) {
      // Handle errors
    }
  });
);


thank you ian. do you also mind to provide some input on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79259921/credentialmanager-clearcredentialstateasync-yields-error-clearcredentialstateas also, can android team consider of extending the GoogleSignInClient's sunset deadline? i only realize this when i saw such a message in google play console.
