CredentialManager clearCredentialStateAsync yields error "clearCredentialStateAsync no provider dependencies found"
I am using
implementation 'androidx.credentials:credentials:1.3.0-alpha02'
// optional - needed for credentials support from play services, for devices running
// Android 13 and below.
implementation 'androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.3.0-alpha02'

There seems to have some bug(s) in CredentialManager's clearCredentialState.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314926460?pli=1
Based on the tracker, to solution is to use 1.3.0-alpha02.
However, I am getting
androidx.credentials.exceptions.ClearCredentialProviderConfigurationException: clearCredentialStateAsync no provider dependencies found - please ensure the desired provider dependencies are added

when I perform the following simple test.
    Context context = MyApplication.instance();

    // Initialize the CredentialManager instance
    CredentialManager credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context);

    // Create a request to clear the credential state
    ClearCredentialStateRequest request = new ClearCredentialStateRequest();

    credentialManager.clearCredentialStateAsync(
            request,
            null, // pass in a CancelationSignal to allow cancelling the request
            Runnable::run, // Execute the callback immediately
            new CredentialManagerCallback<Void, ClearCredentialException>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Void result) {
                    Log.i("CHEOK", "Handle success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ClearCredentialException e) {
                    // Handle errors
                    Log.i("CHEOK", "Error = " + e);
                }
            }
    );

Do you have any idea how can I resolve such an error? Thanks.

The "issuetracker" post you're referring to is about 8 months old, so versions have changed. You can either use the latest beta version (see here) or the latest stable (see here). If the issue persists, then please open a bug.
